How to reset the ignored tags in android studio logcat?
In android studio logcat window, you can right click on a tag, then choose "ignore tag 'abc'" to exclude it.
But how can I restore it?

You can simply open the Preferences by using Cmd + , on MacOS and reset or add new tags to ignore. I'm not sure about the Windows shortcuts, but should be accessible from File

